# printing out a line twice after keyPressed

Tags: java, processing

I have created a monopoly game, and the problem right now is that once I press "y" to buy a property, it prints out the previous lines again, rather than going straight through the loop.

```
if (board1[pos_l].getType().equals ("prop")) {
            if (board1[pos_l].getAvail() == (true) && numClicks!=0) {
           println (board1[pos_l].getName() + " is available for $" + board1[pos_l].getPrice() + ". Press y to buy.");
           println("player 2 roll the die (a) if player 1 doesn't buy it");
           println("");

              if (key == 'y' ){
                board1 [pos_l].setAvail(false);
                board1[pos_l].setOwner (name1); 
                p1money = p1money - board1[pos_l].getPrice(); 
                println("you have bought it! you now have " +p1money + ". player 2 press 'a' to roll the die.");
                numClicks=0;
              }
            }
```

I expect the output to be "you have bought it! you now have $___ .....". Instead, it's printing out "board1[pos_l].getName() + " is available for $" + board1[pos_l].getPrice() + Press y to buy. player 2 roll the die (a) if player 1 doesn't buy it" again after I press y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling it **not** to print out the lines when the user presses Y. You need to move those lines to an `else` block:

```
if (board1[pos_l].getAvail() == (true) && numClicks!=0) {
  if (key == 'y' ){
    board1 [pos_l].setAvail(false);
    board1[pos_l].setOwner (name1); 
    p1money = p1money - board1[pos_l].getPrice(); 
    println("you have bought it! you now have " +p1money + ". player 2 press 'a' to roll the die.");
    numClicks=0;
  } else {
    println (board1[pos_l].getName() + " is available for $" + board1[pos_l].getPrice() + ". Press y to buy.");
    println("player 2 roll the die (a) if player 1 doesn't buy it");
    println("");
  }
}
```